# DHCP on Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit with Motorola Netopia Router 2247-62

Tags: router, dns, ipconfig

I have set up DHCP in my Motorola Netopia Router, and have this also set on my laptop, i.e, to obtain IP and DNS automatically.

In the router, I have set up my ISP DNS servers...

> Primary DNS Server
>   159.134.0.1 dns1.eircom.net 
>   Secondary DNS Server
>   159.134.0.2 dns2.eircom.net

When I run ipconfig /all from a cmd prompt on the PC, I get the following:

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Atheros AR9285 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter

   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : C4-17-FE-2F-85-B5

   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes

   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::4922:63e4:d867:b9ac%12(Preferred)

   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.11(Preferred)

   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0

   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 12 June 2011 12:29:33

   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 12 June 2011 14:17:52

   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.254

   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.254

   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 331618302

   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-12-EF-1B-82-00-26-9E-F0-F9-3A

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.254

   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

So, even though I have set up the DNS sever addresses in the Router, my Laptop is showing the Gateway/Router IP as my DNS server(s).

My question is, how can I get the actual DNS server IP's on my PC? using the *ipconfig* DOS command?

TIA for all replies :)

Comment: if I remember right, you can telnet into that box and turn dns relay off

Answer (score 3):

That is just the way some routers work. Unless your DHCP Server setup in the router allows you to specify the DNS server, it will use itself and proxy all requests on your behalf. I checked the documentation, and it did not look like there was a place to specify the DNS server options that it will give out when a DHCP request is made.

In that case, if you really want to use a different DNS server, you can set that and still get the IP address from DHCP. I attached a screen shot showing this.

http://www.netopia.com/support/hardware/technotes/CQG_121.html (near the bottom)

http://www.netopia.com/support/hardware/manuals/SoftwareUserGuideV761-Clsc.pdf

[image]

Comment: Well thank you very much indeed, very helpful and useful. I will take a look at the docs you refer to, thanks again.